# Self aware Eloquent Model implements Strategy Pattern

Tags: architecture, php, laravel

I'd like to be able to have a (Eloquent) Model implement a class based upon a property of the model once it is created. I think this is the Strategy Pattern, but since I'm doing it from inside a Model and not passing the dependency, it's not the perfect fit. I'm trying to avoid using switch or if-else blocks to create the `CompanyXXX` APIs, because there are currently 4 `CompanyXXX`, and it's already unwieldy and we could have up to 20 in a few years.

Example:

```php
interface API
{
    public function getThings();
}

class CompanyOne implements API
{
    public function getThings()
    {
        // Company One API specific stuff to get Things
    }
}


class Property extends Model
{
    // This is an Eloquent Model, this valid is populated from the DB
    public $company; // 'CompanyOne'

    // This is the class implementing the API to use based upon $company
    private $api;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->api = new $this->company;
        // Thus, this is an object CompanyOne
    }

    public function getThings()
    {
        $this->api->getThings();
        // CompanyXXX API specific stuff to getThings
    }
}
```

Thus, I would be able to do things like this in a Controller so it knows which API to use (based on $api) and just does it™. I don't need to know or care what API this Property is using, I just need to getThings.

```php
$property = Property::find(1); // get from DB, has 'api' parameter set

$things = $property->getThings();
```

Which is wildly more simple compared to current methods that use switch and are now difficult to maintain (we now have 46 switch statements in the code base):

```php
$property = Property::find(1);

switch ($property->api) {
    case 'CompanyOne':
        $api = new CompanyOne;
    case 'CompanyTwo':
        $api = new CompanyTwo;
    // repeat
}

$things = $api->getThings();
```

### So what's the question?

1. Is this the Strategy Pattern (modified)? Is this another pattern?
2. Is there a better way (especially in Laravel) to have multiple API classes (as in my example) that are determined from a model's parameter that is 'self-aware' to implement the correct class/system to reduce the use of switch and if-else statements?

Answer (score 2):

It's not the strategy pattern - whether it's a modified strategy pattern depends on how far you want to stretch. I'm not sure this approach has a name, because you can't really do this (exactly) in most other languages. The `$company` field would have to be some kind of factory method in C#/Java/C++.

I haven't done any PHP programming in a *long* time, so I'm not the best person to ask for best practices. Right now I can't really see why you shouldn't use this capability of PHP, if it really helps you.

However, I also can't really see why you would wrap the API creation like this in the first place. It seems `Property::find($x)` could just return an instance of `API` directly.

If you need the `Property` class to provide additional functionality, you could inject the `API` object directly, rather than having `Property` create it.

Comment: I had a typo that `Boss` should be `Property`. I've edited it above. I apologize for the confusion. `Property::find($x)` returns a `Property` object, of which API it tries to connect to is decided by the $company field/value.

Comment: No problem, I figured it would be.